# Refresh ListView in Flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, async-await

How can I refresh a `ListView` ?
Let say in page A, I have a `ListView`, and there is a menu icon in the row item.
When I click the menu icon, it will show a bottom sheet dialog which has a delete icon.
When delete icon is clicked, it will pop up a delete confirmation dialog.
Once the 'Yes' button in confirmation dialog is clicked, it will delete the item. Once it received the "Success" status, it will refresh the `ListView`.
This is the code for bottom sheet delete icon

```
 onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
          var result =  PopUpDialog().showDeleteDialog();   // pop up confirmation dialog
          if (result == 'Success') {
                print('success');
                setState(() {
                  data.removeAt(index);
               });
           } else {
               print('fjeodpedp');
           }
         },
```

And this is the code for `Yes` button in confirmation dialog.

**PopUpDialog-showDeleteDialog**

```
  onPressed: () async {
      Navigator.pop(buildContext);   // dismiss confirmation dialog
          var result = await _bloc.delete();
          return result;
    },
```

**Bloc class**

```
Future delete() async {
    Response delete = await _repo.delete();  // delete data in server
    var deleteResponse = Response.fromJson(delete.body);
    return deleteResponse.status;   // return Success
  }
```

I want the **setState** get called only if **deleteResponse.status** is equal to **success**, but it keep printing `fjeodpedp` once the confirmation dialog is pop up. I have added async-await, but still not working.

What is the correct way?

Thanks for your valuable time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're not waiting for your dialog confirmation. You should use await method to wait for the result of that dialog. I don't know what you wrote in

```
PopUpDialog().showDeleteDialog();
```

method but it should be async to perform the after operations.

For now you can write this statement to resolve the error.

```
var result =  await PopUpDialog().showDeleteDialog();
```

Or you can also do this if you showDeleteDialog() is async ->

```
PopUpDialog().showDeleteDialog().then((result){
if (result == 'Success') {
                print('success');
                setState(() {
                  data.removeAt(index);
               });
           } else {
               print('fjeodpedp');
           }

});
```

Try this and let me know whether it works or not.

**Update**

```
int showDeleteDialog({Function onSuccess, Function onFailure}) {
    _bloc = Provider.of<Bloc>(context);
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext buildContext) {
          return AlertDialog(
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  child: Text('YES', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Navigator.pop(buildContext);
                    var result = await _bloc.deleteWorkOrder();
                    if(onSuccess!=null) onSuccess(result); <------ Here you can pass your result directly to the function.
                    return result;
                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Text('CANCEL'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if(onFailure!=null) onFailure();
                    Navigator.of(buildContext, rootNavigator: true)
                        .pop('dialog');
                  },
                )
              ],
              title: Text(Localization.of(buildContext).deleteDialogTitle),
              content: Text(Localization.of(buildContext).deleteDialogContent));
        });

    return 0;
  }
```

Your success function would be like this

```
onSuccess(result){
           if (result == 'Success') {
                print('success');
                setState(() {
                  data.removeAt(index);
               });
           } else {
               print('fjeodpedp');
           }
}

onFailure(){
//Add your failiure logic here.
}
```

Comment: @Tony it won't work this way because you're directly returning 0 in the return so you'll return 0 every time.

Comment: You can do one thing pass your current function as argument in the showDialog method. And call that function on the confirmation. If you're confused then i can give you a short demo about it.

Comment: Updated the answer. Please take a look

Comment: I still don't understand. What is onSuccess and onFailure?

Comment: @Tony that would be your after process functions which you want to execute after a result. Let me edit my answer with those two functions.

Comment: Where should I place the  onSuccess function and OnFailure function (The last part of your code) ? Isn't in Page A ?

Comment: Yes these functions should be in Page A and your openDialog function should be in another file as you did in your code.

Comment: If I create onSuccess and OnFailure function separately, index cannot be resolved as it is attach to the listView itemBuilder.

Comment: Pass that index into showDialog method and then re-pass that index into success function. This way you can manage that issue.